# rancher stuck Waiting to register with Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, rancher

I use rancher to create an EC2 cluster on aws, and I get stuck in "[Waiting to register with Kubernetes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9zgp.png)" every time, as shown in the figure below.
You can see the error message "Cluster must have at least one etcd plane host: failed to connect to the following etcd host(s)" on the Nodes page of Rancher UI. Does anyone know how to solve it?

[This is the screenshot with the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9zgp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow installation [guide](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/cluster-provisioning/rke-clusters/node-pools/ec2/#3-create-a-cluster-with-node-pools-using-the-node-template) carefully.

When you are ready to create cluster you have to add node with etcd role.

> Each node role (i.e. etcd, Control Plane, and Worker) should be
> assigned to a distinct node pool. Although it is possible to assign
> multiple node roles to a node pool, this should not be done for
> production clusters.
>
> The recommended setup is to have a node pool with the etcd node role
> and a count of three, a node pool with the Control Plane node role and
> a count of at least two, and a node pool with the Worker node role and
> a count of at least two.

Only after that Rancher is seting up cluster.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the exact error (either dns or certificate) by logging into the host nodes and seeing the logs of the container (docker logs).

download the keys and try to ssh to the nodes to see more concrete error messages.